# Multiple ajax queries after clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a table with delete and refresh buttons at every row of table in my app.When I click on this buttons my app adds proper rows to table but 2,4,8 times after 1,2,3 clicks on this buttons respectively. Here is fragments of code with creating a table and handler of buttons.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var methodSelector= {methodName:$.cookie("methodName"), filter: $.cookie("filter")};
    $("table.mainTable").empty();
    $("table.mainTable").prepend(filter_head_rows[$.cookie("filter")]);
    var appendingTable=$.ajax({
        url : "database_functions.php",
        type: "POST",
        data : methodSelector,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            $("table.mainTable").append("<tbody>");
            $("table.mainTable").append(data);
            $("table.mainTable").append("</tbody>");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {

        },
    });
})
    .on("click", ".deleteParticipant", function() {
        var id={id:$(this).parent().parent().find('td#idOfParticipant').html()};
        $.ajax({
            url:"delete.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: id,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {   
                $.cookie("currentPage","content")
                $("#mainContent").load($.cookie("currentPage")+".html");
            }
        });
    })
    .on("click","#refresh", function(){
        if ($("#partner").is(":checked"))
        {
            var partner="true";
        }
        else{
            var partner="false";
        }
        var currentData={
            ticketNumber:$("#ticketNumber").val(),
            paymentDate:$("#paymentDate").val(),
            issueDate:$("#issueDate").val(),
            fio:$("#fio").val(),
            birthDate:$("#birthDate").val(),
            workNumber:$("#workNumber").val(),
            mobileNumber:$("#mobileNumber").val(),
            email:$("#email").val(),
            lpu:$("#lpu option:selected").text(),
            structuralSubdivision:$("#structuralSubdivision").val(),
            position:$("#position").val(),
            category:$("#category").val(),
            categoryDate:$("#categoryDate").val(),
            diploma:$("#diploma").val(),
            speciality:$("#speciality").val(),
            degree:$("#degree").val(),
            secondDiploma:$("#secondDiploma").val(),
            chamber:$("#chamber option:selected").text(),
            notice:$("#notice").val(),
            partner:partner
        };
    })
```

A table:

```
    <table class="mainTable table table-striped">           <thead>         <tr>                <th></th>               <th>Номер удостоверения</th>                <th>ФИО</th>                <th>Дата рождения</th>              <th>ЛПУ</th>                <th>Должность</th>              <th>Моб. тел.</th>              <th>Раб. тел.</th>              <th>e-mail</th>         </tr>           </thead>        <tbody><tr><td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini deleteParticipant"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>У</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini editParticipant" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalWindow"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>Р</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini participantINFO" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalWindowView"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>П</a></td><td id="idOfParticipant">1</td><td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td><td>0000-00-00</td><td>lpu345</td><td>хирург</td><td>+79001234567</td><td>+79001234567</td><td>ivan@gmail.com</td></tr><tr><td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini deleteParticipant"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>У</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini editParticipant" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalWindow"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>Р</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini participantINFO" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalWindowView"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>П</a></td><td id="idOfParticipant">32</td><td>Иванов Иван Иванович</td><td>0000-00-00</td><td>lpu345</td><td>хирург</td><td>+79001234567</td><td>+79001234567</td><td>ivan@gmail.com</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Can you update your question with some example HTML as well?

Comment: Is there any reason you are setting the AJAX call to a variable?

Comment: Well, I don't use this variable next. Should I close ajax query with its help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is probably in the "row" itself, and when you add a new row,
the  `.on("click"...)` trigger is doubled.

Move this JS code outside the template code that is loaded.

Comment: code is in the <script></script> tag before div, so it's not in row, but it's loaded with every ,load() to, where should I put it? In separate file?

Comment: try to move it outside the content returned from the Ajax.
one level upper template file should be fine.